# How can I specify the objects directory makefile?

Tags: c, gcc

How can I specify the directory of the .o files in this GCC command?

`gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror src/*.c`

Comment: You can't.  If you compile multiple files at the same time then there's no way to redirect the output to a different directory.  If you want the output to go to a specifically named file then you have to invoke the compiler one time per source file (e.g., you can't use a wildcard like `*.c`).  I'm not sure why this question has a makefile tag, since you didn't provide any makefile question here.

Answer (score 2):

Use -o to specify the target. You can choose any directory you like.

Comment: `clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files`

Comment: @CosminSerdean - Your question is about GCC. What on earth does Clang have to do with it?